# How to zoom two Images placed side by side, together?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, zooming

I have two scroll-views placed side by side and they can be zoomed individually. I've done this by putting my view inside a scrollview and setting the zoom-scale for the scroll-views. So far, it works fine! Now, there's a new requirement to zoom the two images together so that if I zoom one image, **the other is zoomed automatically with the same zoom scale**. I was given the [roambi app](http://itunes.apple.com/app/roambi-analytics-visualizer/id315020789?mt=8) as reference in which two scrollviews can be scrolled together by scrolling either one of them for convenience during comparison. Basically, what I'm doing is also comparison between the two views. I've gone through scrollview delegate methods but was unable to achieve the required results. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had implemented something similar a while ago (I did it for buttons). This is how I did it:

Take two `UIScrollView`s and reference them (I've used `firstScrollView` and `secondScrollView`)

Take two `UIButton`s and reference them (I've used `firstImgBtn` and `secondImgBtn`). Set the delegates to both the scrollviews and use the following delegate methods:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    //return the respective button in the scrollview to be zoomed
    if(scrollView==firstScrollView){
        return firstImgBtn;
    }
    else{
        return secondImgBtn;
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    // zoom in the other scrollview when one has zoomed
    if(zoomTogether){//a bool to decide whether to zoom the two together or not
        if(scrollView==firstScrollView){
            secondScrollView.zoomScale = firstScrollView.zoomScale;
        }
        else{
            firstScrollView.zoomScale = secondScrollView.zoomScale;
        }
    }
}
```

This can be applied to any subclass of `UIView`-in your case it will be `UIImageView`s

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this, but off the top of my head I would say first you need to get the zooming being the same in both of them (as per above), then you'll have to use the delegate methods to make sure both of your scrollviews have the same contentOffset value.  i.e. when one changes via manual scrolling or via programmatic scrolling, you have to (using the delegate callbacks) set the other one to the same contentOffset value.

EDIT:   As per request, adding a bit of (UNTESTED) code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
  if(scrollView == self.myFirstScroller)
  {
    self.mySecondScroller.contentOffset = self.myFirstScroller.contentOffset;
  } 
  else {
    self.myFirstScroller.contentOffset = self.mySecondScroller.contentOffset;
  }
}
```

and zooming done similarly to above.

But if you're looking for some copy-paste solution you can just drop into your project, I'm afraid you'll have to teach yourself a bit more about scroll views.  You should read the Apple Programming Guide, because scrollviews can be a bit tricky, and you often have to use quite a few of the delegate methods to get things working correctly.